# How to run Mysql as a standalone docker container (without docker-compose)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

So MySql docker has me a bit confused.
All the MySql docker examples I have seen are with `docker-compose` where a volume is mounted to it.

I have some confusion about `mysql` docker image.

- When I do `docker-compose up` it creates some files and then I need to mount it `/var/lib/mysql` for the container to work. Why is this needed and why is it not created inside the container?
- How can I build a Docker image so that all the required files are copied to `/var/lib/mysql`?

The reason I cannot use docker compose is because I want to run mysql as a standalone container in AWS ECS.

Any advice is appreciated.

P.S: I do not need the data to be persistent. Only need it to work while the container is running.

Comment: You need a volume mount to actually store the data, or else it will get lost as soon as the container exits.  In plain Docker you could use the `docker run -v` option to supply this option; I don't know about ECS.  Would a non-container RDS database ($$) be a suitable option here?

Comment: (It's not possible to specify storage in a Dockerfile.  If you do start a MySQL container without a volume mount, it will be functional, but you'll lose data when the container exits.)

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is fine I lose the data once the container is stopped. I do not need the data to be persistent.

Comment: In that case you should be able to just run it without doing anything special, the same way you'd run any other (implicitly stateless) container.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ <= The first example on a single line is `docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag` which will do very exactly what you're looking for. See the rest of the image documentation for more options.